# In C#, can you please tell which is the standard function which raises an INT number into any desired degree?

Tags: c#

In C#, can you please tell which is the standard function which raises an INT number into any desired degree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int answer = (int)Math.Pow(a, b);
```

Unless I somehow misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is Math.Pow() - is it important that it take integers?